# Question on the output of a tricky C++ code about inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing

I have the following piece of C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{
    public:
        int i;
};
class Y: public X{
    public:
        int i;
};


int main()
{
    X ob1;
    X ob2;
    Y ob3;
    ob1.i = 1;
    ob3.X::i=2;
    ob3.i=3;
    ob2=ob3;
    cout << ob2.i;
}
```

I expect it prints 3 (while it does 2) because `ob2.i` seems to me to be equivalent to `ob3.i` which was set to 3 but it seems that the compiler assumes this as the inherited `i` from the class X. Why?

Comment: The behavior is called slicing and this post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing , Take `foo` as `X::i` and `bar` as `Y::i`.

Comment: Also in C++, data member could not be overridden in C++, only virtual funcitons.

Comment: Why do you "expect it prints 3"? `X.i` was never set to 3 anywhere. It was set to 2. `X::i` and `Y::i` have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Just because the shown code sets `Y::i` to 3 does not automatically set `X::i` (of the same object) to 3, too. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @LouisGo Right!

Comment: @Mohammad With full qualifiers, the lines of interest here are `ob3.X::i = 2`, `ob2.X::i = ob3.X::i`, `cout << ob2.X::i`.